# Custom URL Scheme in trigger.io

Tags: ios, trigger.io, url-scheme

I am trying to use [trigger.io's urlhandler directive](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/urlhandler.html) in the config.json file for my app to setup a custom scheme.

I've put the following into the "modules" section:

```
"urlhandler": {
    "scheme": "mytestapp"
}
```

Unfortunately Safari errors out with `Cannot Open Page: Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid` if I try to navigate to `mytestapp://testing`

What am I missing in terms of setting up a custom URL scheme?

Comment: Can confirm that it doesn't seem to work at this point. However, since it was not mentioned in the [official change log](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/release-notes.html), I wouldn't expect it to be final, yet.

Comment: Interesting and good point. Don't realize this was a new feature (just started experimenting with trigger.io yesterday). Would be nice if the documentation pages had file mod dates.

Comment: Whoops - my mistake, I pushed the docs too early... this is coming very soon. Will update here when it's ready.

Comment: urlhandler module was included in v1.4.15 of the platform!

Comment: @Brad, did you manage to get urlhandler work ?

Comment: Quentin - handled my problem a different way I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it ended up being released on September 25th.
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html